# Query max value

Tags: python, pandas

How can I query the employment with the highest salary from each department:

```
Employment    Salary    Department
Alex          10000       Sales
Joe           20000       Sales 
Chris         30000       Mar
Tony          40000       Mar
```

Desired Output

```
Employment    Salary     Department
Joe           20000        Sales
Tony          40000        Mar
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['Department'], as_index=False).max()`

Comment: What if there are 2 employees with the same highest salary in Sales?
I have tried your code and it only shows one.

Comment: `df[df['Salary'] == df.groupby('Department')['Salary'].transform(max)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can first group by Department and then apply `.max()`:

```
print(df.groupby(['Department'], as_index=False).max())
```

Comment: That only shows one of the employees with the highest salary in each department, not all of them. In other words, it works with the given sample data, but that data doesn't cover that specific situation which is likely to happen in real life.

Comment: It_is_Chris seems to have nailed it with `df[df['Salary'] == df.groupby('Department')['Salary'].transform(max)]` ìn a comment to the question above.